# Angular: How can I access and modify an item inside a scope list?

Tags: angularjs, database, list, post, scope

edit: syntax error.

inside my application, before an item is posted to the database, I want to modify it.

Here is what i've tried:

```
  $scope.submitForm = function () {
        $scope.input[2] = 9001;
        $http.post('database/entries', $scope.input)
            .success(function (data) {

            }).error(function (data) {

            });
    };
```

For reference, $scope.input looks like:

```
{"name":"matt","code":"a21","powerLevel":5,"isAwesome":true}
```

Comment: you seem to have your syntax a bit off here.  `$scope.input` appears to be an object, not an array, and doesn't have a property named `2` that can be set.  It's not exactly clear what you really want to change, but if you are trying to change `powerLevel` (which is what `[2]` would  be if it were an array), then `$scope.input.powerLevel=9001;` should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, i hope this example help you to figure out how can find an abject from the list[array].
>
> In this example we use $filter to search in the list; [you can run the example & check browser console]

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $filter){
    
    $scope.list = [
      
       {"name":"matt","code":"a21","powerLevel":5,"isAwesome":true},
       {"name":"jon","code":"a22","powerLevel":5,"isAwesome":true},
        
    ]; 
      
      
    $scope.findItemInTheList = function(item){
      //search by code : you can do it by anything
      var findItem = $filter("filter")($scope.list, {code: item.code}, true)[0];
      findItem.name = "change it";
      findItem.powerLevel = "change it";
      findItem.isAwesome = "change it";
      console.log(findItem);
    };  
    
  
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in list">
          {{item.name}} 
          <button ng-click="findItemInTheList(item)">modify & post</button>
        </li>
      </ul>  
    
  </body>
</html>
```